# How can I store data in a JavaScript Array so it can be stored in local storage?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a basic web store and I'm looking for a way to store data that I already have in an Excel sheet in a JavaScript array so that I can store it in the local storage if the buyer clicks on "Add to cart", for example:
I have this data right here:

`['Hoodie','Purple','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (1).jpg']`

`['Hoodie','Light Blue','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (2).jpg']`

`['Hoodie','Green','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (3).jpg']`

as you can see, it's the type of clothing, color, description, price and source of image

how can I store this in a JavaScript array so that I can create a function that upon clicking a button, adds the specific item in local storage?

Comment: Whatever way you design your data it won't change the fact, that `localStorage` may _store_ only strings. So, as long as your data can be `JSON.stringify()`'ed (and `JSON.parse()`'ed back) you're good to go.

Comment: Yup, thats what I want to do but I'm not sure how to add a whole list of hoodies in one javascript array and upon clicking, only adds one of them, something like JSON, my apologies if my explanation isn't clear enough I'm still a beginner

Comment: Upon each click you do `localStorage.getItem(yourArrayItemName)`, parse the content into array, modify that (by pushing necessary items), (over)write your local storage item with modified array (using `localStorage.setItem()`) and you're done. However, using local storage for application _state_ [may not be a good idea from performance standpoint](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/).

Answer (score 1):

First off...  from a data structure point of view, your solution is: interesting

```
['Hoodie','Purple','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (1).jpg']

['Hoodie','Light Blue','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (2).jpg']

['Hoodie','Green','cotton authentic',' Only £39.99','images/items/hoodies/hoodie (3).jpg']
```

Generally, in an array, you want to have multiple things that are all the same kind of thing.   Yes, here each hoodie is represented as an array...  and all the elements of each array are strings...  but each string represents some entirely different type of thing.

Really, you should be using objects to store the hoodies:

```
{
    type: 'Hoodie',
    color: 'Purple',
    material: 'cotton authentic',
    price: '£39.99',
    image: 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (1).jpg'
}
```

Now you have a single thing that has specific attributes each with a value

To show all of your hoodies, you have your array.. but now you load that array with those objects instead of having separate arrays

```
var hoodieArray = [{
    type: 'Hoodie',
    color: 'Purple',
    material: 'cotton authentic',
    price: '£39.99',
    image: 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (1).jpg'
},
{
    type: 'Hoodie',
    color: 'Light Blue',
    material: 'cotton authentic',
    price: '£39.99',
    image: 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (2).jpg'
},
{
    type: 'Hoodie',
    color: 'Green',
    material: 'cotton authentic',
    price: '£39.99',
    image: 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (3).jpg'
}]
```

Now, you have a way to store, within a single key in the localStorage, the array of separate objects each with its list of attributes simply by passing in JSON.stringify(hoodieArray)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for, thanks a lot
although, is there a way for me to convert over 100 arrays like the 3 I provided into a neat object like yours?

Comment: I'm sure there is some way to assist with that.. but would need to see the code you have now that shows how you are getting/setting up your current arrays.

Comment: @Moz check my edited answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70297431/1363169

Answer (score 0):

If you have the array in numbers and want to clean them up to array of object.

For instance, let say you have arrays like the following :

```
let allArray = [
    ['Hoodie', 'Purple', 'cotton authentic', ' Only £39.99', 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (1).jpg'],

    ['Hoodie', 'Light Blue', 'cotton authentic', ' Only £39.99', 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (2).jpg'],

    ['Hoodie', 'Green', 'cotton authentic', ' Only £39.99', 'images/items/hoodies/hoodie (3).jpg']

]
```

provided you are sure of the position of each element in the sub array, you, the code below will transform all to array of object.

```
allArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.type = element[0]
    obj.color = element[1]
    obj.material = element[2]
    obj.price = element[3]
    obj.image = element[4]
    allArray[index] = obj
})
```

you can have a look at what you get in the console

```
console.log(allArray)
```

so, you can then add the reformed array to localstorage like this :

```
localStorage.setItem("mycart", JSON.stringify(allArray))
```

However, in an ideal scenario, items are added to the cart one at a time. To add an item at a time you can write a function to add item to cart and another one to get cart items  as given below

```
addToCart(item) {
        let items = getCartItem()
        items = items == null ? [] : items
        let found = items.find(x => x.somethingUnique == item.somethingUnique)
        if (found == null || undefined) {
            items.push(item)
            localStorage.setItem("mycart", JSON.stringify(items))
            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
```

**Note**

```
 let found = items.find(x => x.somethingUnique == item.somethingUnique)
```

Replace `somethingUnique` with anything that is unique to each object, like **ID** etc. This is to check if an element already exist in the cart, and therefore avoids duplicates with the code

```
getCartItem() {
        let item = localStorage.getItem("mycart")
        item = item == null || undefined ? null : JSON.parse(item)
        return item;
    }
```

I hope this helps.